# reactive form control with json as default value

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Hi I am facing an issue with reactive form control usage. For mat-select I have a default JSON array with name and id. Of which I am showing only name in the drop down. I want to set a name as default using similar JSON but I am not able to do that. Kindly suggest:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup
    data: any
    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.stateList = [{
            name: 'def',
            id: '1'
        }, {
            name: 'ghi',
            id: '2'
        }];
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            state: {
                name: 'abc',
                id: '1'
            }
        })
    }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Color</mat-label>
   <mat-select [(value)]="state.name" formControlName="state">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let state of stateList" [value]="state">
     {{ state.name }}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: try `this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      state: ['abc']
    })`

Comment: NEVER use [(value)] and formControlName in the same tag. after this, is in the mat-option [value]="state" you can use this.formBuilder.group({state:stateList[0]}) -must be the same object- or use the property compareWith https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect. Another aproach is use in option [value]="state.id" and give the value of the "id"

Comment: Hi piyush
Thank you for replying but I need it to be a JSON with id and name only. I have a requirement for this particular format. So I has to be "state: new FormControl({value:{
                name: 'abc',
                id: '1'
            }, disabled: false},[Validators.compose()])"